# Trouble joining table / Select statement inside Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

One table has an "item" column with SKU numbers including dashes (We'll call it DASHDB) while the other table has an "item" column with SKU numbers without dashes (We'll call it NODASH_DB). I need to join these two tables.

I know I can do something like this:

```
FROM (SELECT REPLACE (ITEMDASH,'-','') AS ITEMNO FROM DASHDB) AS NEWITEMNO
LEFT JOIN NODASH_DB ON NEWITEMNO.ITEMNO = NODASH_DB.ITEMNO
```

However, I am already pulling data from other tables and this is about four joins down.

I tried:

```
LEFT JOIN (SELECT REPLACE(ITEMDASH,'-','') AS ITEMNO FROM DASHDB) AS NEWDB ON NEWDB.ITEMNO = NODASH_DB.ITEMNO
```

But it's not accepting the right database. Using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 17.

Comment: The best solution would be to fix the data. Storing dashes in one place and not the other is a recipe for disaster both from a data perspective and performance.

Comment: I completely agree. However, the data is being pulled from an ERP system. We aren't entering it differently, that's just how the system is storing it in the different tables. So frustrating.

Comment: Can you add a computed column to remove the dashes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to tell without sample data, but this should work:

```
LEFT JOIN DASHDB 
ON REPLACE(DASHDB.ITEMDASH,'-','') = NODASH_DB.ITEMNO
```

For example, see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/36879/1

Comment: YOU ARE MY HERO! Thank you so much :) That worked perfectly.